# template class specialization with common functionality independed of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

This is more a compiler-related question.

```
template<InputStream T>
class JpegImage
{
    static void do_something_independed_of_T() {}
    void do_something_else_independed_of_T() {}
```

In the code above we have a static function and a non-static function, both of them independed of `T`.

The question is this: Does "the compiler" understand independence and generate source for them only once, or source for them generated for each different `T` used?

I know that "It is compiler-specific" but it is not enough for me. If g++ and 2-3 other compilers does not regenerate the code, this means than code does not regenerated, so, if bodies of that functions are REALLY big, there is no need to move them outside template class.

Comment: In my tests, both g++ and clang generate separate implementations even though the assembly is identical. This is with both `-O3` and `-Os`.

Comment: fwiw, the language says that the member functions are different for every instantiation of `T`.